# router-link that links to child route inside v-for gets called multiple times (Vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, v-for

this is my first question I cannot find an answer to, so I am posting this here now.

I have a component which has a list of courses that are rendered via a v-for loop. For each course I have a router-link that links to the detail page of that course. Like so:

```
 <div class="courses">
    <div
      class="course"
      v-for="(course, $courseIndex) in semester.plannedCourses"
      :key="$courseIndex"
    >
      <router-link
        class="course-content-container"
        :to="{
          name: 'baseModalParentCourse',
          params: { code: course.code, semester: semesterName.name },
        }"
      >
        <div
          class="course-content-container-content"
        >
          <div class="course-content-container-content-text">
            <p class="course-content-container-content-text--code">
              {{ course.code }}
            </p>
            <p>{{ course.name }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The routes I defined looke like this:

```
{
path: "/my-studyplan",
name: "StudyPlan",
component: StudyPlan,
children: [
  {
    path: ":code/:semester",
    component: BaseModalParentCourse,
    name: "baseModalParentCourse",
  },
  {
    path: ":parentCode/:code/:semester",
    component: BaseModalChildCourse,
    name: "baseModalChildCourse",
  },
],
```

},

Whith each click on a course, the `baseModalParentCourse` modal opens and loads stuff. But looking at the console and the output of some test code in the created hook of my modal, I see that it get's created as many times as items are in the current row (so if there are 6 courses, it get's called 6 times, but each time with only the course I clicked).

I don't know why this is happening. If I change the routes from being children to "normal" routes, it is not happening, but I loose the context of the "my-studyplan" route, which I would like to still have open in the background.

Can anybody tell me why the router-link seems to be called as many times as there are courses? And why it's not happening if I don't define the route as children?

Thank you in advance!

---

UPDATE

So I found the solution myself after a while:

I was putting the  which I didn't even include in the snippet inside the loop, instead of in the parent component where it actually belonged. That meant that the modal was opened that often because the outer loop was running several times and each time the view was rendered.

Comment: Note: `params: { code: course.code, semester: semesterName.name },` - `semesterName` is undefined

Comment: @ShayaUlman It's defined in the data attributes. (did not copy the whole file here)